# only last 11 notification is notify

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

i am working on local notification, i want to notify 20 notification at the same time

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i<=20; i++) {


        NSString *my_date1 = @"2015-10-1 16:36:00";
        NSDateFormatter *frmt1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [frmt1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *mydate1 = [frmt1 dateFromString:my_date1];
        NSLog(@"date:::  %@",mydate1);

        notification.fireDate = mydate1;
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

    }
}
```

can anybody help me why only last 11 notification is displayed? is there any limitation of IOS? or am i wrong any where?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any issue in your code, however on system notification bar it will show the counter as 11. but if you expand the tray, you will see all the notifications i.e 20. Note that in device settings, maximum number of notification for an app can be set.

I tried below code to fire the notifications which worked perfectly, however displayed 11 notifications received on the top notification bar.

```
for (int i = 1; i<=20; i++) {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:5 sinceDate:[NSDate date]];;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```